# Can we use two or more firebase projects in one app?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently working on my admin project before this i have two separate projects in which both apps use firebase. and now i want to manage both apps in my admin panel. so i wanted to integrate both app but i can only connect one of them.

`firebase.js`

```
import { initializeApp, getApp, getApps } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore/lite";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
};

const app = getApps().length ? getApp() : initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = getFirestore(app);
const storage = getStorage(app);

export { db, storage };
```

`fbase2.js`

```
import { initializeApp, getApp, getApps } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore/lite";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY_2,
        authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN_2,
        projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID_2,
        storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET_2,
        messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID_2,
        appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID_2,
};

const app = getApps().length ? getApp() : initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db2 = getFirestore(app);
const storage2 = getStorage(app);

export { db2, storage2 };
```

but it only read the first config. is there a way that i can merge all my firebase projects.

Comment: You have to give at least one of the two projects a unique name when you initialize it.

Comment: @DougStevenson You've closed the question. but the recommended answers that i get is not working. i initialize my second project config with a unique name given but it's still reading the main firebase.

Comment: Then you should post a new question with the new code you have that doesn't work the way you expect, and share your debugging details.  There should be enough information in the question that anyone can use the reproduce the specific problem you observe.